# Extract file name with PHP and make redirect URL

Tags: php, string, url, permalinks

i have a file with name `2011-08-21-filename.php`

I want to extract the date and the title, so the permalink will be something like `/2011/08/21/filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filename = "2011-08-21-filename.php";
preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\w*).php/', $filename, $matches);
$path = implode("/", array_slice($matches, 1)); // => string(19) "2011/08/21/filename"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$filename = str_replace(".php", "", preg_replace("/[0-9-]/", "", $string));
$directory = $dir.$filename;
```

quick solution, sorry I'm not that great with regex